# Is there a way to send an alert in-case the Search Service Full crawl execution time exceed certain amount of time

Tags: 2013, search, administration, crawling, sharepoint-on-prem

We have a sharepoint server on-premise 2013 enterprise edition. and today i noticed that new content on our site collections are not being indexed (new content will not show on the search results). so i access the "Central Administration" >> "Managed Services" >> "Search Service", i found that the Full crawl execution time is around 323 hour and it is still running. so i stopped the full crawl , then re-index the search service, re-run the full crawl and every thing is working well now.

But my question , is how i can set an alert on the search service, so if the search service full crawl execution time exceed certain amount of time (let say exceed 1.5 hour) to send an email to our sharepoint admin? is this possible ?

Comment: Are you scheduling full crawls; if so, why?

Comment: @TrevorSeward Yes i define a schedule to run a full crawl each day at 5 am , and an incremental crawl each 10 minutes.. is there any problem with this ?

Comment: Generally you should only run Full Crawls as a last-ditch effort to resolve an issue (and of course the initial crawl). Instead, don't schedule FCs and use Continuous Crawls. FCs cause index refreshness issues, which is more of an issue with a large amount of content where there would be many hours prior to a FC completing. That said, scheduled FCs are generally unnecessary.

Comment: @TrevorSeward this is the first time i hear something like this,, i always schedule full crawls to run once a day,, and inside my current environment i do so since around 3 years without facing any problems... until last week  i notice that the full crawl is taking forever